# Making vowels in a charArray lowercase

Tags: java, arrays, string, char, lowercase

First time posting here, so I have this assignment where we make a code that reads a file and writes it into another one, except in uppercase, however we also need to add a statement to exempt vowels from being uppercase.

Main:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // write your code here
    String iFilePath, oFilePath;
            iFilePath = "C:\\Users\\flame\\Desktop\\New folder\\FileforRead.txt";
            oFilePath = "C:\\Users\\flame\\Desktop\\New folder\\FileforWrite.txt";
    UpperCaseFile ucf = new UpperCaseFile(iFilePath, oFilePath);


    }
}
```

UpperCaseFile class:

```
package com.company;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.String;

import static java.lang.Character.toLowerCase;

public class UpperCaseFile {

    public UpperCaseFile(String iFile, String oFile) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String input;
        String output;


        File file;
        file = new File(iFile);
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

        PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(oFile);

        while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
            input = inputFile.nextLine();

            output = input.toUpperCase();

            outputFile.println(output);

            char[] charArray = iFile.toCharArray();


            for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++)
            {
                if ( charArray[i] == 'a' || charArray[i] == 'e' ||
                        charArray[i] == 'i' || charArray[i] == 'o' ||
                        charArray[i] == 'u')
                {
                    charArray[i] = Character.toLowerCase(charArray[i]);

                }

           inputFile.close();
            outputFile.close();
            }


        }
    }
}
```

In all honesty, I can't seem to find the error, at least my IDE isn't saying so and it always ends with finishing the process with exit code 1. All help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: a) `outputFile.println(output);` you output the text then you try to alter it - too late it is already written  b) you are closing the files in the `while` / `for` loop.  c) `iFile.toCharArray();` - here you are using the fileName, not the text in the file.

Comment: try doing one part of this assignment at once.  Test that part then go to the next step.

Comment: 1. The above is true, try breaking the problem into smaller steps, get each step working.  Smaller problems are easier to solve that the whole thing all at once.  2. `public UpperCaseFile(String iFile, String oFile)` -> `iFile.toCharArray();` uh, no.  You can't take the char array of the **NAME** of the file and expect anything useful.  You'll have to read the file with a BufferedReader or similar and convert the lines.  Please ask your instructor for help, you are way off base here.

Comment: @markspace Potentially what the OP is doing `input = inputFile.nextLine();
` is OK

Comment: What is the error? Exactly what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

I have added comments, what you need to do, and what wrong you are doing here. try to write code what I have said in comment. If you face any issue do comment here will help along way. I am not providing code for problem since it is assignment.

```
while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
        input = inputFile.nextLine();

        output = input.toUpperCase();
        // here you will do, what you want to do.
        // you will take output string and find vowel and convert those 
        // into lowercase. Keep in mind that all characters along with
        // vowels are already capitals, so find all capital vowels and convert 
        // those to lowercase
        // after above operation you can write into outputfile

        outputFile.println(output);
        // this is not doing what you are doing
        /* char[] charArray = iFile.toCharArray();


        for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++)
        {
            if ( charArray[i] == 'a' || charArray[i] == 'e' ||
                    charArray[i] == 'i' || charArray[i] == 'o' ||
                    charArray[i] == 'u')
            {
                charArray[i] = Character.toLowerCase(charArray[i]);

            }*/
        //You need to close file after doing operations.
        // these lines should not be in while
       //inputFile.close();
       // outputFile.close();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've been trying to make it work for the past few hours to no avail, I've tried a bunch of different things. This is where I'm at right now: 
while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
input = inputFile.nextLine();
output = input.toUpperCase();
char [] arr = output.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < output.length(); i++) {
if (arr[i] == 'A' || arr[i] == 'E' || output.charAt(i) == 'I' || arr[i] == 'O' || arr[i] == 'U') {
Character.toLowerCase(arr[i]);
  }
 Sorry if I'm slow, still quite new to this